# TikZ library "external" breaks page number count in focus theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, page-numbering, tikz-external, themes

I like the Beamer [focus](https://github.com/pcafrica/focus-beamertheme/tree/main) theme, however, when I use it with
TikZ library external, it breaks the page number count in the footline. Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Simple frame 1}
  This is a simple frame.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Simple frame 2}
\tikzexternalize
  This is a simple frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If building with

```bash
pdflatex  -shell-escape focus-demo.tex
```

I get `2/1`, rather than `2/2`, as the last frame number.

This is likely due to the fact that the number is calculated by
[beamerouterthemefocus.sty](https://github.com/pcafrica/focus-beamertheme/blob/main/beamerouterthemefocus.sty)
as a tikzpicture.

Probably this can be worked out by a `\tikzexternalize` and `\tikzexternaldisable` in the .sty file, but how to do this in the document?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem if you only switch the externalisation on for the pictures which need it:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/export=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Simple frame 1}
  This is a simple frame.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Simple frame 2}
\tikzset{external/export=true}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  This is a simple frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems that if I use `\tikzexternaldisable` in the preamble and `\tikzexternalize`on the second frame (after the `\titlepage` frame), there are no problems. But I need more testing to be sure of this.